# Are contradictory definitions of cathode/anode (in conventional cf) explained by two ways of conceptualizing the circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, terminology

For consistency let's just consider conventional current flow; we can imagine it as positively charged holes.

I don't want an electrochemical (or even historic) explanation, just a consistent naming convention for working with electronic components.

As an example of what kind of "definition" I am talking about, there is the CCD "conventional current departs device", but it does not specify whether "device" can be battery or sink (e.g. diode), and is for those contradicts what "departs" means.

Maybe the definition can be cleared by different concepts of "circuit": if it were a circle, then the positive holes would move from the "+" marked terminal of a battery through wires and components finally to the "-" marked terminal of the battery where they disappear.

But this circle-concept contradicts with how we draw circuits: we draw a diode's "+" marked terminal connected through a wire to the battery's "+". If we are talking about positive holes departing from the diode then they should be reversed.

So it would make more sense to see the circuit as two parts: some wires are in the positive part, some wires are in the negative part. (If a wire would go directly between the battery's terminals then it would be in the short-circuit part and we would repair that).

What is your consistent concept of circuit and, following from that, definition of cathode/anode?

Comment: I know I get confused by 'anode' and 'cathode' and refuse to engage with the vocabulary. I just look at the data sheet for whatever device I'm trying to use, and check current flow. Conventional current leaves the positive terminal of a battery, sorted.

Comment: @Neil_UK that's a way to handle it. (And it underlines the problem)

Comment: It's called "conventional current" and not positively charged holes and, as EE's we default to using conventional current whenever we talk about current so, no need to rename it. CCD normally stands for charge coupled device: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device and not what you called it. I'm not sure what the question is all about or why there is a problem here.

Comment: @Andyaka (1) I know conventional current and I have written it in my question (2) CCD is also a mnemonic look it up (there are often multiple meanings of an acronym, that's fine) (3) if you don't understand the question, move along

Comment: The anode is the terminal which conventional current flows into. For a battery (when powering a circuit), the anode is the battery's negative terminal. When charging a battery, the anode is the positive terminal. Please don't be rude to people giving free help. The terminology has got nothing to do with voltage as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Andyaka I did not want to be rude

Comment: It seems you are having trouble with a different convention, that of current for sources (generators of electricity) and sinks (consumers of electricity). For a generator (conventional) current exits the positive terminal; for a sink (conventional) current enters the positive terminal. Consider a capacitor: when you are charging it (cap is a consumer), current flows into the positive plate, but when you discharge it onto a load (cap is a generator), current flows out of the positive plate. Is this the inconsistency you are referring to?

Comment: @SredniVashtar Yes this is just a different way of expressing my model of considering the wires in the positive and negative part of the circuit. How would you define cathodes in your model?

Comment: @ben cathode is the terminal where the current exits the device (positive for a generator, negative for a sink), while anode is the terminal where current enters a device (negative for a generator, positive for a sink). So, when you connect for example a battery to an electrolytic cell you must hook up cathode of the battery (current out) with anode of the cell (current in), with both these terminals being positive. ( The only exception in circuit theory are Zener diodes because we hook'em up backwards to exploit their reverse bias characteristic).

Comment: Come to think of it, the fact that the cathode of a battery (that  is reduced) needs to be connected to the anode of a cell which is oxidated is probably the reason we have the source-sink convention. Mnemonics: "OXANa has a RED CAT".

Comment: @SredniVashtar thank you, your examples are helpful

Comment: You're welcome. I would have made an answer, but this site has an history of closing question when they are not understood, so...

Comment: is this a philosophy question, or about EE? What is CF in the title?